# SQLSERVER Management Objects in c++ Programming

Tags: sql-server

How to use SQLSERVER SMO in C++(CPP) to list all the servers availabel and find databases installed using VS2003/VS2005 IDE.

And i need some clarification in

1)Does Vs2003 Have support for SQLSMO??
2)Is any additional files(reference) needed to work with SMO in VS2003? if yes what r those?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) was released with SQL Server 2005, and requires .NET 2.0 at least. VS 2003 only supports .NET 1.x.

In .NET 1.x, you'll have to revert to SQL-DMO - a COM based set of components for managing SQL Server database objects.

Marc